# Get current filename with URL parameters

Tags: php, filenames

Say the user is loading the following page: `www.example.com/myDirectory/myPage.php?answer=yes`
And I want to use PHP to get `myPage.php?answer=yes` from that. However, `basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])` only returns `myPage.php`. How would I do that?

Comment: PHP parse_url() will return an array of domain,file and get variables.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can append the query string after you [get](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php) it as an [environment variable](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php):

```
$myurl = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) . "?" . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
```

If you need to consider the possibility of no query string, add a conditional test:

```
$myurl = strlen($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) ? basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])."?".$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] : basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
```

Comment: This returns `/myDirectory/myPage.phpanswer=yes`. I want `myPage.php?answer=yes`.

Comment: @Mooseman you can explode on `/`, and get the last element in the resulting array

Comment: The only problem with this is that if there are no parameters present, we still have the `?`.

Comment: DRY! `$myurl = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']).(strlen($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) ? "?".$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] : "");`

Answer (score 9):

it is easier?:

```
basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])
```

Comment: i don't know; tell me!

Answer (score 1):

For URLs with trailing parameters the following will place the first part of the current URL (i.e. the part before ?) within the variable $current_url[0] and then print it out.

```
<?
$current_url = explode("?", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
echo $current_url[0] ;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']
```

will give you the paramaters